# Left join in DPLYR with a greater than condition

Tags: mysql, r, dplyr

I am trying to do a left join using DPLYR with additional greater/smaller than conditions in my left join.

Equivalent in SQL would be

```
select a.*, b.Tag 
from table1 a 
left join table2 b 
on a.id =b.id 
and a.value >= b.valueL 
and a.value <= b.valueH

Table1                Table2 
ID value              ID ValueL ValueH Tag
x  1                  X  3      6      1
x  5
x  10

Desired output:
ID value Tag
x  1     Null  
x  5     1
x  10    Null
```

I found sources suggesting to join on x and filter afterwards

```
left_join(table1, table2, by = c("id" = "id") %>%
  filter(value >= valueL & value <= valueH)
```

But this eliminates 2 rows and gives the below ouput

```
ID value Tag
x  5     1
```

Comment: Filtering after the join is appropriate if you wanted an `inner_join`. For a `left_join` you should rather fill the `Tag` values with `NA`, something like `left_join(...) %>% mutate(Tag = case_when(value >= ValueL & value <= valueH ~ Tag, TRUE ~ NA))`.

Comment: left_join on id will only work if the table2 has 1 row per id. If it has multiple, it will add rows to the output.

Answer (score 1):

In the devel version of `dplyr`, we can use `join_by` that also does the non-equi join

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(table1, table2, by = join_by(ID, value >= ValueL,
     value <= ValueH)) %>% 
   select(names(table1), Tag)
# A tibble: 3 × 3
ID    value   Tag
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 x         1    NA
2 x         5     1
3 x        10    NA
```

---

Or use `powerjoin`

```
library(powerjoin)
 power_left_join(table1, table2,
   by = c( ~  .x$value  >= .y$ValueL &  .x$value <= .y$ValueH), 
    conflict = coalesce_xy) %>% 
  select(names(table1), Tag)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  ID    value   Tag
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 x         1    NA
2 x         5     1
3 x        10    NA
```

---

Or use `data.table` join

```
library(data.table)
 setDT(table1)[setDT(table2),  Tag := i.Tag, 
    on = .(ID, value >= ValueL, value <= ValueH)]
```

-output

```
> table1
   ID value Tag
1:  x     1  NA
2:  x     5   1
3:  x    10  NA
```

#### data

```
table1 <- structure(list(ID = c("x", "x", "x"), value = c(1, 5, 10)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -3L))

table2 <- structure(list(ID = "x", ValueL = 3, ValueH = 6, Tag = 1), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -1L))
```

Comment: This solution looks perfect. Unfortunately, we are using an older version of dplyr in my current environment.